# lateinit property navController has not been initialized

Tags: android

I was following the official developer.android.com code labs when I encounter this issue

1. In the MainActivity, you should already have code to set up the app bar (also known as action bar) with the nav controller. Make navController a class variable so you can use it in another method.

   ```
   class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_main) {

   private lateinit var navController: NavController

         override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

         val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager
              .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
         navController = navHostFragment.navController

          setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
      }
   }
   ```
2. Within the same class, add code to override the onSupportNavigateUp() function. This code will ask the navController to handle navigating up in the app. Otherwise, fall back to back to the superclass implementation (in AppCompatActivity) of handling the Up button.

   ```
   override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
      return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
   }
   ```
3. Run the app. The Up button should now work from the FlavorFragment, PickupFragment, and SummaryFragment. As you navigate to previous steps in the order flow, the fragments should show the right flavor and pickup date from the view model.

This is my android studio error
[image: Android Studio Error]

Comment: Should be `navController = navHostFragment.navController`, in your screenshot it's `val navController = navHostFragment.navController`

Comment: yup, i managed to fixed it thanks